# How to create excel file from existing excel file in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I will have a master excel file stored in one of the SP list. On the button click I have to create new excel file by reading master template and need to modify some cells and store new file in separate SP List.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated..